# How to import with bulk insert into SQL Server? Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)"

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

Total row count from `sekolah.txt` is 9 million, I tried to import using bulk insert like this

```
bulk insert [report].[dbo].[bulk test]
from 'D:\FTP-NSM\Sekolah\sekolah.txt'
with 
(
     fieldterminator = ';',
     rowterminator = '\n',
     errorfile = 'D:\FTP-NSM\Sekolah\Error\error.csv',
     maxerrors = 100000
)
```

But a message is :

> Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an
>   error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server
>   "(null)".

Comment: Does the file `sekolah.txt` exist on the machine on which you are doing the bulk insert?  Is the file well-formed?  What does the `error.csv` file say, if anything?

Comment: yes sekolah.txt is exist, i want take error data (data that are not imported) to error.csv

Comment: Use ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a' instead of '\n' and try again.

Comment: thnks @steryd , but it still not work

Comment: Have you tried to use format ([fmt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190393.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) file?

Comment: yes i have tried use .fmt but message error is same

Answer (score 0):

I found arrow icon (maybe from merge in cmd) in the last line of sekolah.txt , removed it then try again and its solved me